# Remove branch from all submodules

Tags: git

I have a project with a lot of submodules and I want to delete all remote branches named foo in the submodules, *if it exists*.

I am trying to following:

```
git submodule foreach git push origin :foo
```

This works as intended if the branch exists in *all* submodules, but if any of the submodules is missing the branch, the foreach stops:

```
Stopping at 'modules/bar'; script returned non-zero status.
```

How do I suppress the error?

Comment: Instead of the colon prefix, you can now use `--delete`. From `git help push`: "All listed refs are deleted from the remote repository. This is the same as prefixing all refs with a colon."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [git submodule man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-submodule):

> A non-zero return from the command in any submodule causes the processing to terminate. This can be overridden by adding || : to the end of the command.

This means the following should do the job:

```
git submodule foreach 'git push origin :foo || :'
```

The `||` is an OR and executes the next command if the first one returns non-zero, the `:` returns true.